# CakePHP Router::url not working correctly

Tags: php, routes, cakephp-2.0

I'am using CakePHP 2.0 for a small admin section of a website. 
If the user is logged in correctly, I redirect them to the admins dashboard.
I do this as following:

```
$this->redirect(Router::url(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'dashboard')));
```

The redirect is done correct, but for some reason the URL where it redirects to isn't correctly build. The URL is in the following structure (note the double [root] sections in the URL - this is what is wrong):

```
http://localhost/[root]/[root]/admin/dashboard
```

Off course their are errors shown because this controller / action doesn't exists. The URL should be off this form:

```
http://localhost/[root]/admin/dashboard
```

I can't seem to find what the exact problem is since cakePHP is not my core dessert, is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried without using Router::url() inside the redirect??

Comment: I didn't try it yet, because I know the Router::url way should work ass well... There must be a specific reason that it's not working, and I would like to know why... Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @www.creative-geeks.com: I am also getting the same issue. Have you found the solution for it.

Comment: @Mohini I never found a solution, I skipped CakePHP since it wasn't that necessarily to use it. If you ever find the issue, do let me know please!

Comment: @www.creative-geeks.com: hmm ok. Will let you know for sure, if I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply right like this

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'full_base' parameter in Router::url.
e.g.

```
$url = Router::url( array( 
    'controller' => 'posts',
    'action' => 'view',
    'id' => $post[id],

    'full' => true
    ) );
```

This will give you a full base url. I found this fixed routing problems when I was running CakePHP in a subdirectory of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect("YOUR URL");

example $this->redirect('/admins/dashboard');
```

This way you can redirect easily!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply right this 
`Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));`